# Return new instance of a class from within itself in a static method?

Tags: c#

Okay i now you can do this as i do it, but i want to know if it can be done more seamlessly as an "auto" property kinda thing.

```
class Test : PPCNode
    {

        public static PPCNode ParseCode(string code)
        {
            string[] codeArray = SplitCode(code);

            // return instance of the Instruction Node
            return new Test(codeArray, 0);
        }
    }
```

So that's basically the code per say.

Now, this code happens in Many classes, so it's identical, except the instance is for the class it's within.

so that's what i wonder, is it possible to make a new instance through some kind of auto thing, like.

"return new ThisClass(....)" if you get my meaning.

Thanks:)

EDIT:

Okay here come some examples, this will be Much code but it's easy to look through.

So here are Two Classes:

```
internal class AddicDotInstructionNode : PPCNode
    {
        private readonly string[] parameterArray;

        private AddicDotInstructionNode(string[] codeArray)
        {
            parameterArray = codeArray;

            // Throw exception if the number of parameters is invalid to instruction
            if (codeArray.Length != 3)
                throw new Exception($"\"{GetType().Name}\" instruction is invalid");
        }

        public static PPCNode ParseCode(string code)
        {

            // Split the code string into an array so each element is a parameter
            string[] codeArray = code.Split(',');

            // return instance of the Instruction Node
            return new AddicDotInstructionNode(codeArray);
        }

        // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
        // | 0                                 5 | 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 14 15 | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 |
        // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
        // |                  13                 |      D     |        A       |                       SIMM                      |
        // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
        public override int Compile()
        {
            int opcode = 13;

            int regD = Utility.PPCUtility.GetParameterDigit(parameterArray[0]);
            int regA = Utility.PPCUtility.GetParameterDigit(parameterArray[1]);
            int simm = Utility.PPCUtility.Get16bitHexorDecimalAsUint(parameterArray[2]);

            // opcode at 0-5 (26-31)
            // Register D at 6-10 (21-25)
            // Register A at 11-15 (16-20)
            // SIMM at 16-31 (0-15)
            return opcode << 26 | regD << 21 | regA << 16 | simm;
        }
}
```

internal class AddicInstructionNode : PPCNode
    {
        private readonly string[] parameterArray;

```
    private AddicInstructionNode(string[] codeArray)
    {
        parameterArray = codeArray;

        // Throw exception if the number of parameters is invalid to instruction
        if (codeArray.Length != 3)
            throw new Exception($"\"{GetType().Name}\" instruction is invalid");
    }

    public static PPCNode ParseCode(string code)
    {

        // Split the code string into an array so each element is a parameter
        string[] codeArray = code.Split(',');

        // return instance of the Instruction Node
        return new AddicInstructionNode(codeArray);
    }

    // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    // | 0                                 5 | 6 7 8 9 10 | 11 12 13 14 15 | 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 |
    // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    // |                  12                 |      D     |        A       |                       SIMM                      |
    // +-------------------------------------+------------+----------------+-------------------------------------------------+
    public override int Compile()
    {
        int opcode = 12;

        int regD = Utility.PPCUtility.GetParameterDigit(parameterArray[0]);
        int regA = Utility.PPCUtility.GetParameterDigit(parameterArray[1]);
        int simm = Utility.PPCUtility.Get16bitHexorDecimalAsUint(parameterArray[2]);

        // opcode at 0-5 (26-31)
        // Register D at 6-10 (21-25)
        // Register A at 11-15 (16-20)
        // SIMM at 16-31 (0-15)
        return opcode << 26 | regD << 21 | regA << 16 | simm;
    }
}
```

And here is the Caller for those classes:

```
internal static class IntegerArithmeticInstructionNode
    {
        // PowerPC: Table A-2 Integer Arithmetic Instructions (Complete)
        public static Func<string, PPCNode> ParseInstruction(string code)
        {
            switch (code)
            {
                // Addx
                case "add": return AddInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "add.": return AddInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "addo": return AddInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "addo.": return AddInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Addcx
                case "addc": return AddcInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "addc.": return AddcInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "addco": return AddcInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "addco.": return AddcInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Addex
                case "adde": return AddeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "adde.": return AddeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "addeo": return AddeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "addeo.": return AddeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Addi
                case "addi": return AddiInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Addic
                case "addic": return AddicInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Addic.
                case "addic.": return AddicDotInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Addis
                case "addis": return AddisInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Addmex
                case "addme": return AddmeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "addme.": return AddmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "addmeo": return AddmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "addmeo.": return AddmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Addzex
                case "addze": return AddzeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "addze.": return AddzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "addzeo": return AddzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "addzeo.": return AddzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Divwx
                case "divw": return DivwInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "divw.": return DivwInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "divwo": return DivwInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "divwo.": return DivwInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Divwux
                case "divwu": return DivwuInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "divwu.": return DivwuInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "divwuo": return DivwuInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "divwuo.": return DivwuInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Mulhwx
                case "mulhw": return MulhwInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "mulhw.": return MulhwInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;

                // Mulhwux
                case "mulhwu": return MulhwuInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "mulhwu.": return MulhwuInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;

                // Mulli
                case "mulli": return MulliInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Mullwx
                case "mullw": return MullwInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "mullw.": return MullwInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "mullwo": return MullwInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "mullwo.": return MullwInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Negx
                case "neg": return NegInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "neg.": return NegInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "nego": return NegInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "nego.": return NegInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subfx
                case "subf": return SubfInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subf.": return SubfInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subfo": return SubfInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subfo.": return SubfInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subx (equivalent to Subf with swaped rA and rB)
                case "sub": return SubInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "sub.": return SubInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subo": return SubInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subo.": return SubInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subfcx
                case "subfc": return SubfcInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subfc.": return SubfcInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subfco": return SubfcInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subfco.": return SubfcInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subcx (equivalent to Subfc with swaped rA and rB)
                case "subc": return SubcInstrucionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subc.": return SubcInstrucionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subco": return SubcInstrucionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subco.": return SubcInstrucionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subfe
                case "subfe": return SubfeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subfe.": return SubfeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subfeo": return SubfeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subfeo.": return SubfeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subfic
                case "subfic": return SubficInstructionNode.ParseCode;

                // Subme
                case "subfme": return SubfmeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subfme.": return SubfmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subfmeo": return SubfmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subfmeo.": return SubfmeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

                // Subze
                case "subfze": return SubfzeInstructionNode.ParseCode;
                case "subfze.": return SubfzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeRc;
                case "subfzeo": return SubfzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOe;
                case "subfzeo.": return SubfzeInstructionNode.ParseCodeOeRc;

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the ton of code, but as you can see it's basically same thing over and over, but each class has a difference, often within the same category they only differ by 1 or 2 constant values.

So, as there is much copy pasting and reusing almost the same class over and over, i try to find ways to make some of it more seamless.

Hence why i thought returning itself auto would be nice as i wouldn't have to rename the copy paste for that every time, some small time earned;P

Comment: There are ways to move the code around, but I'm not sure what you think should work in terms of making it more seamless. Perhaps a more complete example of what you want to work?

Comment: Sure will give a more clear picture:)

Comment: Are u asking for some generic static method that provide instance of what class u want???

Comment: No i am asking if for a way for a class to return an instance of itself, just like my first example.
But not by explicitly saying the class, but with some kind of Auto Property.
So i wonder if such a thing exists as i can't find anything about it.

Comment: Got it now, thanks (probably a bit too much code, but then again, maybe not)

Comment: Yeah i didn't know how to split it up so i just copy pasted it just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

Certainly not something as nice as `new ThisClass()`. However, if you are returning a base class you *can* get away with this (not really a good idea for reasons mentioned below, but it works):

```
public static BaseClass ParseCode(string data)
{
    ...
    string declaringType = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType; 
    return (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(declaringType);
}
```

Note that this is crazy expensive compared to just manually invoking your constructor, and you lose some type safety, but it would let you copy-paste.

The trick is using reflection to get the declaring type (the first line) and then using `Activator.CreateInstance` to invoke a constructor on that type. Because that returns `object` you have to cast it to `BaseClass`.

Use this overload of `CreateInstance` to pass arguments to the constructor: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx). Its the same idea though.

Comment: Ah, if it's expensive that's not worth it, kinda sucks.
Much appreciated example though.

There's probably some neater way to what i do overall.

Thanks, will accept this as answer as it does what i asked for:)

Comment: @Zerowalker Reflection never comes cheap :)